# SQL set Table 1 COL A = Table 2 COL B if Table 1 COL C = Table 2 COL D

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables

**Table1**

```
REF1 REF2
     A
     B
     C
```

**Table2**

```
UPN Filename
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

what I want to do in SQL is this

> If Table1 REF2 = Table2 Filename then set Table1 REF1 = Table2 UPN

this is the sql I did

```
UPDATE    Table1
SET       REF1 = Table2.UPN
FROM      Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 
ON        Table1.REF2 = Table2.FileName
```

all this does is take the first value in row 1 of table2 and put it in every row under table1 in `REF1`

eg this is what I get

**TABLE1**

```
REF1 REF2
1    A
1    B
1    C
```

this is what I want

**TABLE1**

```
REF1 REF2
1    A
2    B
3    C
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: Wow what a terrible question title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this in SQL Server, here is the syntax:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.REF1 = t2.UPN
FROM Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.REF2 = t2.FileName
```

Comment: sorry I got my ON ref wrong initially. my apologises. You should see both your answer and my original SQL be the same. If I run it I still get all 1's in REF1 instead of 1,2,3 ? Your answer does not work.

Comment: @Varkanoid Then your data on `Table2` is not exactly the one you posted, since this answer is correct. Most likely you have different values of `UPN` for the same `Filename` on that table.

Comment: Hi its okay its working now. Really weird for some reason it would just not work in the tab I was using so I thought start a fresh. Recopied the answer then closed the tab. So I clicked on New Query posted it back in there and ran it then it worked !